# What is "stagnation in the prostate"?

Tags: prostate

What does "stagnation in the prostate" as described as a clinical symptom in serious evidence-based medicine mean? Or is this just a "pop-culture and mass-media" *buzzword*?

Answer (score 2):

You can search using operators "site:gov" or "site:edu" and find texts, such as this one from [PubMed](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5040619/):

> Sexual behaviors represent potential modifiable risk factors and may
>   influence prostate cancer development through a variety of specific
>   mechanisms. One biological mechanism involves prostatic accumulation
>   of potentially carcinogenic secretions, which may create more
>   opportunity for prostate cancer development, sometimes referred to as
>   the **prostate stagnation hypothesis**.

The term **"blood stagnation"** is not related to prostate stagnation hypothesis and is mentioned as a problem after prostate cancer surgery, for example in [this article about acupuncture treatment after prostate surgery](https://www.acufinder.com/Acupuncture+Information/Detail/Acupuncture+Treatment+of+Incontinence+following+Prostate+Cancer+Surgery+).

Comment: Thank you. I had seem this. Exactly after this I have decided to ask that question. Am I right that this confirms that "prostate stagnation"  is not a clinical symptom description, but just some kind of mental construct?

Comment: It's a hypothesis that suggests a possible risk factor for prostate cancer. It's not a symptom (something what you experience as a feeling or own observation) or a sign (what a doctor can find during an examination). It's a proposed mechanism that has not yet been proven so far, but may or may not be in the future. New hypotheses (this one is several decades old, though) often comes with new terms that at the time sound "constructed" but later become widely accepted, such as irritable bowel syndrome, for example.

Comment: https://www.newscientist.com/article/dn3942-masturbating-may-protect-against-prostate-cancer also talks about this

Comment: Some pop medicine articles talk about blood stagnation others about prostate secret stagnation.  I would like to ask authors of https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5040619/ why you need those weakly defined terms? and why it is not enough to stay just with "ejaculation frequencies"? What I do not understand there? Symptom defined through statistics is common place now?

Comment: I added a link to an article that mentions blood stagnation, which is not related to prostate stagnation hypothesis. Scientists often invent new terms. The term prostate stagnation focuses on the mechanism. It's their business how to name something and you can like it or not.

Comment: I agree that such name focuses on mechanics, but question is "what is also known about this mechanics?" (complaints, observable degenerative changes)  - in other words is it a symptom or just a "name".

Comment: In cancers, in general, mechanisms are rarely known in detail. But risk factors are often known. To see what is currently known about the mechanism of prostate stagnation, you can read what has been published so far. I don't know. But this mechanism, if it really exists, does not need to cause any symptoms. Just like atherosclerosis is a mechanism involved in coronary heart disease, but may have no symptoms for a long time.